# Reliability of p-value in scipy.stats.spearman

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, sample-size, spearman-rho, t-distribution

I am puzzled about the following sentence in the documentation of the [function calculating Spearman's rank correlation coefficient in the scipy.stats package](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3198-L3342):

> "The p-values are not entirely reliable but are probably reasonable for datasets larger than 500 or so."

In the beginning, I interpreted the sentence as saying that the p-values are probably reasonable for data sets larger than 500 or so, but not entirely reliable for smaller data sets.

I am puzzled because the main test statistic used in the function assumes a t-distribution. (I'm not sure whether this is the only statistic used, because for certain cases the function switches to mstats_basic.spearmanr seemingly using another test statistic) This seems to be a valid assumption only if the sample size is small as for example mentioned here:

http://www.janda.org/c10/Lectures/topic06/L24-significanceR.htm

My question is, thus, what the justification for the sentence mentioned above could be or whether the sentence is rather meant in a way that could be paraphrased like this:

> For datasets larger than 500 or so the p-values are not entirely reliable but are probably reasonable.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Best,

Dominik

Answer (score 1):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8789) in the scipy issues tracker, there was insufficient evidence to support the sentence in question and it appeared that the consensus was to remove it, though it's still in the docs at the time of my writing.

So I would disregard the sentence.